# Call contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt on Click instead of Long Press

Tags: ios, uitableview

I took my lead from this tutorial: https://kylebashour.com/posts/context-menu-guide

I thought I had everything, yet when I click on the row, nothing happens

UPDATE: Thanks a comment I learned that contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt is called on a long press. Is there a way to call this on a click? I wanted to give users several options for contacting the people listed. But buttons in UITableViewCell doesn't seem to work, so a context menu is the best I can think of, but a long press isn't obvious for interacting with this table view.

```
import UIKit

class PeerSupportVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var peerSupportTableView: UITableView!
var supportArray: NSArray = [];
fileprivate var configuration = Configuration.sharedInstance;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.peerSupportTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.peerSupportTableView.delegate = self;
    self.peerSupportTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.peerSupportTableView.rowHeight = 200.0
    getPeerSupport();
    
}



func getPeerSupport(){
    
    self.supportArray = ["One","Two","Three"]
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.peerSupportTableView.reloadData()
    });
}


}




extension PeerSupportVC: UITableViewDelegate {


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let item = self.supportArray[indexPath.row]

        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { suggestedActions in

            let phoneAction = UIAction(title: "Phone Call", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")) { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    print("Wants to Phone Call");
                });

            }

            let textAction = UIAction(title: "Text Messsage", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.badge.plus")) { (action) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    print("Wants to Text Message");
                });
            }

            return UIMenu(title: "Contact Options", children: [phoneAction, textAction])
        }
    }


}


extension PeerSupportVC: UITableViewDataSource{



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("Count of Support Array:",self.supportArray.count);
    return self.supportArray.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath);
    for viewToRemove in cell.subviews {
        viewToRemove.removeFromSuperview();
    }
    let width = self.peerSupportTableView.frame.width;
    
    if let result = self.supportArray[indexPath.row] as? String{
        print(result);
        
        
    
        let NameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 180, y: 0, width: width-155, height: 30));
        NameLabel.textColor = .black;
        NameLabel.text = " "+(result);
        NameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight(rawValue: 400));
        NameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        cell.addSubview(NameLabel);

        
        
    }


    return cell;
}


}
```

I dumbed the code down to share, but this lesser version still doesn't work.

What I want to happen is a menu to pop up on the line that was selected and give the user options on how to contact the person they selected. Any help on displaying the menu would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt` is called (by default) on a long-press on the cell -- which appears to work as expected with the code you posted. As a side note, though, your `cellForRowAt` code is ***horrible!!!***

Comment: If you have any constructive criticism of the cellForFowAt, I would love to hear it. But as it stands it works, and if it is stupid and it works, then it isn't stupid.

Comment: I didn't say it was "stupid" -- I said "horrible." Create a cell class, and reuse it. Removing and re-adding subviews in `cellForRowAt` pretty much defeats the purpose (and memory management) of reusable cells. If you're only going to have a total of 3 rows, it doesn't matter... but it's unlikely one would use a table view for 3 rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, here's your code, modified to use a reusable cell:

```
// simple cell class, based on your code
class PeerCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let nameLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nameLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight(rawValue: 400))
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 180.0),
            nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
        ])
    }
    
}

class PeerSupportVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var peerSupportTableView: UITableView!
    var supportArray: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // register our custom cell
        self.peerSupportTableView.register(PeerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        self.peerSupportTableView.delegate = self;
        self.peerSupportTableView.dataSource = self;
        self.peerSupportTableView.rowHeight = 200.0
        getPeerSupport();
    }
    
    func getPeerSupport(){
        self.supportArray = ["One","Two","Three"]
    }
    
}

extension PeerSupportVC: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let item = self.supportArray[indexPath.row]
        
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { suggestedActions in
            let phoneAction = UIAction(title: "Phone Call", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")) { (action) in
                print("Wants to Phone Call");
            }
            
            let textAction = UIAction(title: "Text Messsage", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.badge.plus")) { (action) in
                print("Wants to Text Message");
            }
            
            return UIMenu(title: "Contact Options", children: [phoneAction, textAction])
        }
    }
    
}

extension PeerSupportVC: UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Count of Support Array:",self.supportArray.count);
        return self.supportArray.count;
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PeerCell
        
        let result = self.supportArray[indexPath.row]
        print(result)
        cell.nameLabel.text = result
        
        return cell;
    }
    
}
```

As I said in my comment, though, your `contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt` was working as-is -- just need to long-press on the cell to trigger the call.

Comment: Thank you for that, do you have any idea on how to change the trigger from a long-press to a click? 

My preference would be to have multiple buttons in each TableViewCell, but that seems to not be an option, so this context menu was a solution to that. I am not sure a long-press will be understood by users.

Comment: I changed the title of the question to be more in line with what I need, now that I know that the code is working as intended.

Comment: @ChrisAdzima - *"My preference would be to have multiple buttons in each TableViewCell, but that seems to not be an option"* -- why is that not an option? I don't believe you can trigger `contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt` with anything other than a long-press... of course, you could configure your own "menu" and present it on `didSelectRowAt` using `UIPopoverPresentationController`

Comment: In fixing my "horrible" ;) function for cellForRowAt I was able to get the buttons to work, so I am giving you the answer. The whole issue was caused by some code that I was given by a previous developer and just kept using it.

Thanks for the help